# ¿Cómo resolver error HTTP 400 cuando envio un JSONrequest (volley, android)?

Tags: android, json, volley

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación speech to text en android y uso la api de google y volley para ello, pero tengo un problema  cuando intento enviar un json al servidor. Todo el rato recibo el error de http 400. He intentado resolver que pasa o que hago mal y después de dos semanas no he conseguido nada, aquí os dejo el código:

```java
url = "https://netav3a.balidea.com/api/voice";

JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();

try {
    jsonParam.put("text", s);
    jsonParam.put("language", "es-ES");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(jsonParam.toString());

CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

final String mensaje = s;
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Castellano.this);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, jsonParam,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
            Toast.makeText(Castellano.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Castellano.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(error.toString());
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null) {
                Log.e("Volley", "Error. HTTP Status Code:" + networkResponse.statusCode);
            }

            if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "TimeoutError");
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "NoConnectionError");
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "AuthFailureError");
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "ServerError");
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "NetworkError");
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Log.e("Volley", "ParseError");
            }
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json;");
            headers.put("apiKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            return headers;
        }
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("text", mensaje);
            params.put("language", "es-ES");
            return params;
        }
    };

queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

y cada vez que ejecuto el programa me da como resultado esto

```
E/Volley: [198] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for (la url por motivos personales la omito)
I/System.out: com.android.volley.ClientError
E/Volley: Error. HTTP Status Code:400
E/Volley: ServerError
```

Me gustaria saber en que fallo y como arreglarlo, llevo ya mucho tiempo en esto solo y no soy capaz de arreglarlo.

Comment: El servidor es tuyo o estás utilizando el de otro? En el caso de que sea tuyo, lo recives con el método get? Podríamos ver el código de cómo recibes el request?

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia el servidor no es mio, es de la empresa para la que estoy haciendo la app, pero es eso, tengo que enviar un json mediante el metodo get y todo el rato me da el error 400

Comment: Tendrás que preguntar si esperan el json en el body, en un request o en algún otro formato. Al parecer tal y como lo mandas tu no vale.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia la cosa es que el formato de el json es este -> {"text":"Bienvenido, ¿qué desea?","language":"es-ES"} y lo crea perfectamente, lo pruebo en el postman y funciona correctamente, pero al enviarlo no se, error 400

Comment: Si, eso está bien. Pero sin saber que es lo que ellos necesitasn ( por ejemplo un HttpServletRequest o un @RequestBody) no se puede continuar.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia vale, muchas gracias, preguntaré exactamente que necesitan y te pregunto, que estoy de practicas y nunca hiciera esto antes

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia lo que necesitan es un jsonbody, o eso me comentó la chica que lo hizo

Comment: Pues la verdad es que tengo mis dudas de que en un GET se pueda meter un body.

Comment: yo como ya te digo no tengo ni idea, entonces no se si se puede, he probado el json en el programa postman y funciona bien con el metodo get @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia

Comment: Hola!
Un error 400 es "request error" podrías intentar mandar el request en una herramienta externa como Postman y luego recién implementarlo en tu código. El posible error puede que estés mandando un formato que el servidor no entiende.